# Using \ifthenelse inside an option

Tags: macros, errors, conditionals, ifthenelse

I'm trying to create a `\newcommand` for images which takes width as an optional parameter. This is my current command which works (but doesn't use the parameter):

```
\newcommand{\introimg}[3]{
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Figures/#1}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#2}
\end{figure}
}
```

Now I replace `0.9` with the optional parameter using an `\ifthenelse` which provides a default value, `\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{0.9}{#4}` if the option wasn't specified.

```
\newcommand{\introimg}[4]{
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{0.9}{#4}\textwidth]{Figures/#1}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#2}
\end{figure}
}
```

But this generates errors:

```
Runaway argument? width=\ifthenelse {\isempty { Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
```

I see a number of examples include `%` in their examples, I didn't see that in the documentation and don't understand the use for `%`. But I tried to copy their syntax and still got errors.

Comment: On the use of `%` signs in TeX code see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use a conditional. The optional argument of a command is `#1`, so you should define your command in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\introimg}[4][.9]{
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{Figures/#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
\end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\introimg{Foo}{Caption}{Fig:foo}
\introimg[.7]{Foo}{Caption}{Fig:foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, I was playing with that syntax but was having trouble figuring it out. I presume that optional arguments have to go first, which might have been my crux.

Comment: @davidparks21 Yes, at least in commands defined with `\newcommand` the optional argument is always `#1`, with its default value specified in the second `[ ... ]` in the definition.

Answer (score 5):

Use a real optional argument

```
\newcommand{\introimg}[4][0.9]{
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{Figures/#2}
    \caption{#4}
    \label{#3}
\end{figure}
}
```

to be called like

```
\introimg{filename}{label}{caption}
```

or

```
\introimg[0.5]{filename}{label}{caption}
```